# Take n random elements from a List<E>?

Tags: java, algorithm, random, sampling

How can I take n random elements from an `ArrayList<E>`?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to make successive calls to the `take()` method to get another x elements, without replacement.

Comment: what have you got so far? If you get another x elements, can you pick elements from the previous set again, or must be all different all the time until ALL elements are picked? (Then, what next?)

Comment: Without replacement.  When you have no more left, you should get nothing back.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Two main ways.

1. Use [`Random#nextInt(int)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29):

   ```
   List<Foo> list = createItSomehow();
   Random random = new Random();
   Foo foo = list.get(random.nextInt(list.size()));
   ```

   It's however not guaranteed that successive `n` calls returns unique elements.
2. Use [`Collections#shuffle()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29):

   ```
   List<Foo> list = createItSomehow();
   Collections.shuffle(list);
   Foo foo = list.get(0);
   ```

   It enables you to get `n` unique elements by an incremented index (assuming that the list itself contains unique elements).

---

In case you're wondering if there's a Java 8 Stream approach; no, there isn't a built-in one. There's no such thing as `Comparator#randomOrder()` in standard API (yet?). You could try something like below while still satisfying the strict `Comparator` contract (although the distribution is pretty terrible):

```
List<Foo> list = createItSomehow();
int random = new Random().nextInt();
Foo foo = list.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> System.identityHashCode(o) ^ random)).findFirst().get();
```

Better use `Collections#shuffle()` instead.

Comment: I have got a list of 4000 words and I have to get 5 words out of that list each time I press the refresh button, am using the 2nd option of your answer. How much does it guarantee that I will get unique values all the time i.e. what's the probability ?

Comment: @Prateek: If you have a question, press "Ask Question" button. Do not press "Add comment" or "Post Answer" button.

Comment: I know when to use which button, my comment is somewhat related to your already posted answer so I didn't want to create a new thread of if and was looking for a response inline, thanks anyways.

Comment: Keep in mind that Collections.shuffle() uses a version of the Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm, with an internal instance of Random.

The Random class uses a long for its seed value, meaning it can only offer you up to 2^32 possible permutations. This is insufficient for shuffling any more than 12 elements with uniform probability of all permutations (that is, some permutations will never come up). You'll want to use Collections.shuffle(list,random) instead, where random is either and instance of SecureRandom or your own custom Random extension, if you're up to that task.

Comment: Matunos - for what it's worth, the effective seed size of java.util.Random is 2^48, but as you say, it's still worth bearing in mind that you may need to select a better generator. I would still advocate the method I mention of simply picking the items with the relevant probability (you still need the same number of random numbers as a shuffle, but you don't have to swap all the pointers, potentially better memory locality, and there's a chance of terminating the loop "early" once you have selected all of the required elements).

Comment: could you provide another sollution using Stream api and findAny()? it would make the answer up-to-date :)

Comment: @Zavael: findAny() is not suitable here. Using Stream would only add extra code because it doesn't have a builtin random based comparator.

Comment: @BalusC yep thats right, I realized it while trying to implement

Answer (score 41):

Most of the proposed solutions till now suggest either a full list shuffle or successive random picking by checking uniqueness and retry if required.

But, we can take advantage of the Durstenfeld's algorithm (the most popular Fisher-Yates variant in our days).

> Durstenfeld's solution is to move the "struck" numbers to the end of
>   the list by swapping them with the last unstruck number at each
>   iteration.

Due to the above, **we don't need to shuffle the whole list**, but run the loop for as many steps as the number of elements required to return. The algorithm ensures that the last N elements at the end of the list are 100% random if we used a perfect random function.

Among the many real-world scenarios where we need to pick a predetermined (max) amount of random elements from arrays/lists, this optimized method is very useful for various card games, such as Texas Poker, where you a-priori know the number of cards to be used per game; only a limited number of cards is usually required from the deck.

```
public static <E> List<E> pickNRandomElements(List<E> list, int n, Random r) {
    int length = list.size();

    if (length < n) return null;

    //We don't need to shuffle the whole list
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= length - n; --i)
    {
        Collections.swap(list, i , r.nextInt(i + 1));
    }
    return list.subList(length - n, length);
}

public static <E> List<E> pickNRandomElements(List<E> list, int n) {
    return pickNRandomElements(list, n, ThreadLocalRandom.current());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have a situation where I need to remove a small number of elements from a large list, and I was sure shuffling the whole list wasn't the best way to do it, but I was getting hung up on how to remove multiple elements from a list in one fell swoop. Swapping them to the end of the list, and then truncating it, is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to successively pick n elements from the list and be able to do so without replacement over and over and over again, you are probably best of randomly permuting the elements, then taking chunks off in blocks of n.  If you randomly permute the list you guarantee statistical randomness for each block you pick out.  Perhaps the easiest way to do this would be to use [`Collections.shuffle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29).

Comment: And the easiest way to do this is to call java.util.Collections.shuffle()

Answer (score 7):

A fair way to do this is to go through the list, on the nth iteration calculating the probability of whether or not to pick the nth element, which is essentially the fraction of the number of items you still need to pick over the number of elements available in the rest of the list. For example:

```
public static <T> T[] pickSample(T[] population, int nSamplesNeeded, Random r) {
  T[] ret = (T[]) Array.newInstance(population.getClass().getComponentType(),
                                    nSamplesNeeded);
  int nPicked = 0, i = 0, nLeft = population.length;
  while (nSamplesNeeded > 0) {
    int rand = r.nextInt(nLeft);
    if (rand < nSamplesNeeded) {
      ret[nPicked++] = population[i];
      nSamplesNeeded--;
    }
    nLeft--;
    i++;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

(This code copied from a page I wrote a while ago on [picking a random sample from a list](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/random_numbers/random_sample.shtml).)

Comment: bravo -- this should be the awarded answer as it is most modular and portable

Answer (score 7):

Simple and clear

```
   // define ArrayList to hold Integer objects
    ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < maxRange; i++) {
        arrayList.add(i + 1);
    }

    // shuffle list
    Collections.shuffle(arrayList);

    // adding defined amount of numbers to target list
    ArrayList<Integer> targetList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int j = 0; j < amount; j++) {
        targetList.add(arrayList.get(j)); 
    }

    return targetList;
```

Comment: I did not see the correlation between `arrayList` and `targetList`.

Comment: It should've been targetList.add(arrayList.get(j))

Answer (score 6):

As noted in other answers, `Collections.shuffle` is not very efficient when the source list is big, because of the copying. Here is a Java 8 one-liner that:

- efficient enough on random access lists like ArrayList if you don't need many elements from the source
- doesn't modify the source
- DOES NOT guarantee uniqueness, if it's not super important for you. If you pick 5 from a hundred, there's a very good chance the elements will be unique.

Code:

```
private static <E> List<E> pickRandom(List<E> list, int n) {
  return new Random().ints(n, 0, list.size()).mapToObj(list::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

However, for a list with no quick random access (like LinkedList) the complexity would be `n*O(list_size)`.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following class:

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomPermuteIterator implements Enumeration<Long> {
    int c = 1013904223, a = 1664525;
    long seed, N, m, next;
    boolean hasNext = true;

    public RandomPermuteIterator(long N) throws Exception {
        if (N <= 0 || N > Math.pow(2, 62)) throw new Exception("Unsupported size: " + N);
        this.N = N;
        m = (long) Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(N) / Math.log(2)));
        next = seed = new Random().nextInt((int) Math.min(N, Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RandomPermuteIterator r = new RandomPermuteIterator(100);
        while (r.hasMoreElements()) System.out.print(r.nextElement() + " ");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasMoreElements() {
        return hasNext;
    }

    @Override
    public Long nextElement() {
        next = (a * next + c) % m;
        while (next >= N) next = (a * next + c) % m;
        if (next == seed) hasNext = false;
        return  next;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep selecting a random element and make sure you do not choose the same element again:

```
public static <E> List<E> selectRandomElements(List<E> list, int amount)
{
    // Avoid a deadlock
    if (amount >= list.size())
    {
        return list;
    }

    List<E> selected = new ArrayList<>();
    Random random = new Random();
    int listSize = list.size();

    // Get a random item until we got the requested amount
    while (selected.size() < amount)
    {
        int randomIndex = random.nextInt(listSize);
        E element = list.get(randomIndex);

        if (!selected.contains(element))
        {
            selected.add(element);
        }
    }

    return selected;
}
```

In theory this could run endlessly but in practise it is fine. The closer you get the whole original list the slower the runtime of this gets obviously but that is not the point of selecting a random sublist, is it?

Answer (score 0):

The following class retrieve N items from a list of any type. If you provide a seed then on each run it will return the same list, otherwise, the items of the new list will change on each run. You can check its behaviour my running the main methods.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

public class NRandomItem<T> {
    private final List<T> initialList;

    public NRandomItem(List<T> list) {
        this.initialList = list;
    }

    /**
     * Do not provide seed, if you want different items on each run.
     * 
     * @param numberOfItem
     * @return
     */
    public List<T> retrieve(int numberOfItem) {
        int seed = new Random().nextInt();
        return retrieve(seed, numberOfItem);
    }

    /**
     * The same seed will always return the same random list.
     * 
     * @param seed,
     *            the seed of random item generator.
     * @param numberOfItem,
     *            the number of items to be retrieved from the list
     * @return the list of random items
     */
    public List<T> retrieve(int seed, int numberOfItem) {
        Random rand = new Random(seed);

        Collections.shuffle(initialList, rand);
        // Create new list with the number of item size
        List<T> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItem; i++) {
            newList.add(initialList.get(i));
        }
        return newList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> l1 = Arrays.asList("Foo", "Bar", "Baz", "Qux");
        int seedValue = 10;
        NRandomItem<String> r1 = new NRandomItem<>(l1);

        System.out.println(String.format("%s", r1.retrieve(seedValue, 2)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution doesn't modify the original list or otherwise scale in complexity with the list size.

To get a sample of 4 from a list of 7, we just select a random element out of all 7, then select a random element out of the remaining 6, and so on. If we've already selected indices 4, 0, 3, next we generate a random number out of 0, 1, 2, 3, respectively representing index 1, 2, 5, 6.

```
static Random rand = new Random();

static <T> List<T> randomSample(List<T> list, int size) {
    List<T> sample = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int sortedSampleIndices[] = new int[size], i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        int index = rand.nextInt(list.size() - i);

        int j = 0;
        for (; j < i && index >= sortedSampleIndices[j]; j++)
            index++;
        sample.add(list.get(index));

        for (; j <= i; j++) {
            int temp = sortedSampleIndices[j];
            sortedSampleIndices[j] = index;
            index = temp;
        }
    }

    return sample;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All of these answers require a modifiable list or run into performance issued

Here's a swift snippet that required O(k) additional space and is guaranteed to run in O(k) time and doesn't need a modifiable array. (Performs shuffles in a map)

```
  func getRandomElementsFrom(array: [Int], count: Int = 8) -> [Int] {
    if array.count <= count {
        return array
    }

    var mapper = [Int: Int]()
    var results = [Int]()

    for i in 0..<count {
        let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0..<array.count - i)

        if let existing = mapper[randomIndex] {
            results.append(array[existing])
        } else {
            let element = array[randomIndex]
            results.append(element)
        }

        let targetIndex = array.count - 1 - i
        mapper[randomIndex] = mapper[targetIndex] ?? targetIndex 
    }

    return results
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've benchmarked this, focusing on the methods which give k unique results. I compared 3 methods from this page:

1. the swapping method by Kostas Kryptos
2. just plain iterating, and drawing again if the item has already been chosen, as shown by BullyWiiPlaza
3. use aykutfirat's Enumerator to create the indexes to retrieve from the list.

I didn't add the shuffle approach, because I guessed it would clearly be slower than method 1 or 2.

Results with getting 3 items out of a list of 10:

1: 150 ns
2: 145 ns
3: 260 ns

Results with getting 5 items out of a list of 1000:

1: 1362 ns
2: 209 ns
3: 312 ns

It appears that the plain method doesn't really show significantly slower performances with bigger original lists, whereas the swap method does. Apparently the swapping gets expensive with bigger lists.

So best performance is just plain selecting each random item, and doing the draw again if the item was already selected.

Answer (score -1):

The following method returns a new **List of Min(n, list.size()) random elements** taken from the paramenter List list. Have in mind that the List list is being modified after each call. Therefore, each call will be "consuming" the original list returning **n** random elements from it:

```
public static <T> List<T> nextRandomN(List<T> list, int n) {
  return Stream
    .generate(() -> list.remove((int) (list.size() * Math.random())))
    .limit(Math.min(list.size(), n))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Sample usage:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));

System.out.println(nextRandomN(list, 3).toString());
System.out.println(nextRandomN(list, 3).toString());
System.out.println(nextRandomN(list, 3).toString());
System.out.println(nextRandomN(list, 3).toString());
```

Sample output:

```
[8, 2, 3]
[4, 10, 7]
[1, 5, 9]
[6]
```

Comment: It looks like each call to nextRandomN() removes elements from the original list. Any additional calls to nextRandomN() will return an empty list.