# String selection and assigning

Tags: java

```
String a="aaa";
String b="bbb";
String c="ccc";
String d="ddd";

String p,q,r,s;
```

How can I assign values to p,q,r,s
randomly from a,b,c,d?

Like p should have value from a,b,c,d
and similarly for q,r,s

But the value should not repeat.

Comment: Welcome to SO. See @BalusC's answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4702036/take-n-random-elements-from-a-liste. Also, it helps to do a search (here or on Google), before posting new questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do it is probably to just put all the strings in a array (or list, or similar), shuffle the list and assign the first value in the shuffled array to `p`, the second to `q`, etc.

Here's an example of how to do this:

```
String[] strings = new String[] {
    "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"
};

Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(strings));

String p = strings[0],
       q = strings[1],
       r = strings[2],
       s = strings[3];
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of `a,b,c,d`, and use a random `0~3` index to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Add your `Strings` to a `List<String>` and then use `java.util.Random` class's `nextInt(sizeOfList)` method.