# How to recieve 5 random Objects from Room database and add them to a new ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-viewmodel, observers

1. I have method `personViewModel.getNoobs();` which returns `List<Person>` from Room database;
2. I have new  `ArrayList<Person> currentNoobList;` in my Activity.

I need to take 5 random Persons from database and add them to `currentNoobList` in `onCreate()`.

As far as I know, I need to use `.observe` in order to get random Objects from that `List<Person>` which I get using method `getNoobs()`;
but I cannot understand how to write this code correctly. Could you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 onward, something like this would work, provided that there are >= 5 elements in the list:

```
List<Person> personList = personViewModel.getNoobs();
Random random = new Random();
IntStream.range(0,5).forEach(val ->
              currentNoobList.add(personList.remove(random.nextInt(personList.size()))));
```

If you are unable to use Java 8, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702061) could come in handy.

Given that you are using a Room Database, you could add an annotated method stub in your DAO interface and make appropriate changes such that you can  directly get your results via your database. Something like this in your DAO:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM person ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5")
    public List<Person> getFiveRandomPersons();
```

Typically an observer would `observe` a subject; Checkout [Observer Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Given there isn't much information, I believe you are using `Livedata`, since you mentioned `.observe` in context with the Room Database. This  [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata#work_livedata) and this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-livedata-viewmodel#12) might give you some idea on the usage of `observe()`.